# Can I play Mass Effect 2 with 0 Paragon points?

Tags: mass-effect-2

I'm replaying ME2 as a 100% Renegade femshep and I just cured some plague on Omega so Mordin would follow me. I got some Renegade but I also got Paragon.

Is it possible to play through without getting a single Paragon point?

My aim is to be 100% Renegade and get 0 Paragon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its impossible to be purely 100% renegade or 100% paragon.  There are events in the game (like the ones you observed) that will net you both.  Most of them pertain to main quests.

Comment: Dam it! I played ME1 through 100% renegade and now ME2 ruins my streak...

Comment: not really streak if you only did it in one game lol @Coomie

Comment: @Paralytic 20 hours of gameplay and a third of the way through the franchise... I would call that a streak.